# Почему вывод стилей происходит в подвал сайта? WP function.php

Tags: php, wordpress

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_favicon');
add_action('wp_head', 'facebook_open_graph' );
add_action('wp_head', 'add_theme_css_style');
add_action('wp_head', 'add_theme_google_fonts');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_script_footer', 25 );
function add_theme_css_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style ('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_style ('slick-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick/slick.css', array(), '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_style ('slick-theme-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick/slick-theme.css', array(), '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_style ('aos-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/aos/aos.css', array(), '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_style ('woocommerce', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/woocommerce.css', array(), '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_style ('congrats-js-form', get_template_directory_uri() . '/congrats/congrats.css', array(), '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_style ('main-theme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/styles.css', array(), '1.0.0');
}
```

`add_action('wp_head', 'add_theme_css_style');` эта строка отвечает за подключение стилей в хук wp_head
`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_script_footer', 25 );` эта строка отвечает за подключение скриптов в футер(подвал)

**Не нужно сбрасывать ссылки на документацию!!!** Пожалуйста просто объясните почему при `add_action('wp_head', "func_style")` стили все равно выводит в подвале

Спасибо.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_enqueue_scripts

Comment: @DarthKYL  откорректировал вопрос, забыл добавить описание

Comment: Уточните какие установлены плагины и сами ли вы пишете тему или редактируете скачанную/написанную кем-то ещё

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стили идут в футер, потому что вы используете неправильный хук.

Для запуска скриптов **и стилей** надо использовать хук `wp_enqueue_scripts`. На этом хуке WordPress ставит скрипты и стили в очередь. Хук `wp_head` исполняется позднее, смотрите [порядок исполнения хуков](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) в ядре.

На событии `wp_head` с приоритетом 8 (то есть раньше, чем исполняется ваша `add_theme_css_style` - она имеет приоритет 10 по умолчанию) ядро вызывает функцию `wp_print_styles`, которая и выводит стили из очереди на страницу. Любые стили, добавленные после этого, останутся в очереди и будут выведены ядром в футере.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а то не мог никак понять эту документацию.